# How to automate the transfer of a registered user from Drupal to LimeSurvey?

Tags: users

I have a Drupal site which is using the [LimeSurvey Sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/limesurvey_sync) module. All is working fine.

Now I want to automate import user in LimeSurvey when user registered in my Drupal site.

Is there any option to do it?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "transfer" (by editing your question). IMHO it's something different from performing a "page redirect", no? Also check my edit of your question, i.e. using the correct module name, and adding the link to the module's project page. If needed apply any further corrections about that also. Maybe you can clarify also what kind of features are available in LimeSurvey for those users you want to do something with in LimeSurvey? Like does it have some type of "import feature" for such users?

Comment: Hi, this seems to be a question about importing data into something called LimeSurvey Sync, not about Drupal as such (other than Drupal being the source of the data you want to import). The module you linked to has a full list of features, which doesn't include what you're looking for at first glance, so this request would probably make most sense as a feature request to the module

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). There you can check events like "After saving a new user account". And your action would be "Page redirect".

Comment: I am not looking for page redirection. I want to automatic import user in  LimeSurvey after a new user registered on my drupal site.

Comment: I have never used LimeSurvey, but i think one way is, to create your own module an use hook_user_insert(). There is also and [API](http://api.limesurvey.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the rules module to redirect the user on specific page by setting the rule after user registration and also you can alter user registration form and set the user redirect after successfully registration.

Thanks

Comment: No..I am not looking for page redirection. I want to automatic import user in  LimeSurvey after a new user registered on my drupal site.